# Reopen question status

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed, vote-to-reopen

I had a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27770090/point-of-using-ffacet-instead-of-an-attribute-or-a-child-component) that was closed as primarily opinion-based which was completely correct and normal.

Then, I tried to edit my question as I received an interesting and great answer (from a very known user) that IMHO could be useful to the community (specially users working with JSF), the question was also greatly improved by that same user.

So, I voted 20 days ago to repoen my question, and then I noticed that I received 3 other reopening votes (4 in total), but yesterday when I checked again I just saw the *repoen* option without any specification of the number of votes (unlike before). I thought it was declined, but in the *Flagged posts* section I have no declined flags! Is it possible that the reopening vote was renitialized or something like that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reopen votes automatically age away after a while (as do close votes). After four days since the last reopen vote came in, one reopen vote will age away (or "expire"), and then another one will age away each day after that. If at any point another reopen vote comes in, that 4-day period resets. So at this point, all of the reopen votes on your question have expired.

There *were* actually five reopen votes on your question (yours plus four from other users), but yours aged away before any other reopen vote came in. It was in the Reopen Votes queue twice. The first task (after *your* initial edit) resulted in an unanimous decision to leave the question closed, and actually accumulated *four* Leave Closed reviews rather than the usual three. The second task was met with a three-three tie.

I'm reopening the question for you because I don't believe it's opinion-based in its current form.

Comment: thanks for your answer and for reopning :) But, for my curiosity, why when the Leave Closed was decided the flag wasn't declined ?

Comment: @Tarik You cast a custom flag. That requires a moderator to handle it no matter what.

Comment: Oh yes, I mixed up the custom flag I made the first time with my reopening vote, thanks

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/modernize-the-close-vote-aging-logic